# Semantic UI Dropdown is not refreshed when a value changes

Tags: jquery, angular, semantic-ui

I have a UI dropdown created as follows:

```
      <select name="tags" class="ui fluid dropdown" multiple=""
              [(data)]="selectedTagIds" [(ngModel)]="selectedTagIds" id="tagDropdown">
        <option *ngFor="let tag of tags" value="{{ tag.tag_id }}"><i class="icon tag"></i> {{ tag.name }}</option>
      </select>
```

But when the content of tags(the array) is changed, what dropdown displays stays the same until I refresh the page. How can I solve this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where you change the tags value? Can you show me?

Answer (score 0):

Please change the value of name attribute `name="tags"` to something different than model name? Because you are using the same name in name tag and ng-for object.